# ERROR when run wcf service vb on IIS express

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis, service, publish

An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
contract: http://tempuri.org/:IService ----> System.InvalidOperationException: DataContract for type 'B2B_WCF.HttpResponse2' cannot be added to DataContractSet since type 'B2B_WCF.HttpResponse1' with the same data contract name 'HttpResponse' in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/B2B_WCF' is already present and the contracts are not equivalent.
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(Type type)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(Type type)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportType(Type type, String partName, String operationName, XmlSchemaType& xsdType)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
--- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)
at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, the error is obvious.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: DataContract for type
'B2B_WCF.HttpResponse2' cannot be added to DataContractSet since type
'B2B_WCF.HttpResponse1' with the same data contract name 'HttpResponse' in 
namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/B2B_WCF' 
is already present and the contracts are not equivalent.
```

As you can see from the error message, you may have two different contracts with the same name. You can try inspecting the code to merge them or change the name of one of them.